# Constraint layout has to be separate for each field or it will be one parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

I am working on constraint layout for the first time. I am little confused for the fact that it is necessary to have each component on the screen to its own constraint layout in order for it to be responsive or I can just create on parent constraint layout and put all the components inside and it will behave as responsive ?

My xml looks like this at the moment :

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LandingPage"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="179dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Label"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText14"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText14" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/signup_button_background"
            android:text="@string/signupButton"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand very well your question but the main purpose of the constraint layout is to have one parent (the constraint layout) and all views in it, so you have only one level of hierarchy.

I have an exemple for you :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/hubConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hubColorImageView"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/percentageTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_circle"
        tools:tint="@color/blue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        fontPath="@string/fonts_default_regular"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sumTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/hubColorImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="cool title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sumTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="#636363"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        tools:text="54 000,00€" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/percentageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/magnesium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/performanceTextView"
        tools:text="100,0% of contract" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/performanceTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/magnesium"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/percentageTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        tools:text="10000,00 €" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/permanentTransferInfoTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/hubColorImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/percentageTextView"
        tools:text="you have lot of money" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/customBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:foreground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/permanentTransferInfoTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/permanentTransferInfoTextView"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: but when you hard code the value of width and height like you have done in Image view   android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"... will it effect the responsiveness ?

Comment: When you hardcode the height and with, if you want to have responsiveness you will have to set constraint to start and end, or top and bottom and maybe try to play on the constraint bias.
But I think the best way for you to discover the constraint layout is to build it using the design editor, play a little with it and then go back to text and take a look a what field the editor added.

Comment: I have updated my xml in question. my each element contains its own constraint layout. is this approach not correct ?

Comment: You should have only one constraint is your xml. And juste add constraints one views so that they are all placed like you want.

Answer (score 0):

All the layouts which have constraint layout as their direct parent will support all the constraints and work responsively but if you want to have constraints for the views inside other ViewsGroups such as CardView you have to specify a ConstraintLayout inside that too. For such implementations try this [link](http://eugenebrusov.com/cardview-with-constraintlayout/)